# I cannot click anything in KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I want to use KDE (Kubuntu desktop) on my [Acer ES1-711 laptop](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/EE/content/support-product/5573?b=1) with Ubuntu but I cannot click on anything after I boot. 
I tried: uninstalling and reinstalling
It happens when i use my touchpad(which has no buttons,just touch).Kubuntu desktop is on top of Ubuntu

Comment: please provide us helpers with an output of inxi -Fxz between code tags. So we can see what hardware "Acer" is about . Also maybe give a typenumber of that Acer.

Comment: acer es1-711 is my laptop model

Comment: _andri axysto_, a few troubleshooting question: 1) Did you install Ubuntu then KDE on top, or did you install Kubuntu https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/ ? 2) Which version number did you use? 3) Does this happen when you plug a mouse into a USB port? 4) Does this happen if you test with a different flavor of Ubuntu, such as Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Budgie, or Lubuntu https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours ? Please answer by clicking [edit]; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default setting for touchpads on Kubuntu does not allow tapping to be accepted as clicking. Since your touchpad does not have buttons, you'll have to use the keyboard and go to the touchpad settings and enable this function manually.

I'd suggest connecting a mouse temporarily just to enable the setting above and disconnecting it afterwards.